# How to link two tables using foreign key under certain conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to link two tables under certain conditions. Like take one table products( itemno , item, qty, price, stauts) and second table link(Sno, itemno, status). Where itemno and status in link are foreign key referenced to products.

**The question is:-**
*I want the table link to take only those data from products where status is sold and and not unsold*.
.

**The basis code is this :-**

```
CREATE TABLE LINK(
    SNO              INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PRODUCT_ITEMNO   INT NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_STATUS   CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( PRODUCT_ITEMNO,
                  PRODUCT_STATUS )
        REFERENCES PRODUCTS ( ITEMNO,
                              STATUS ) on update CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

What should i add in this to meet up my above mentioned condition.

Comment: this question is vague and somewhat paradox . what is the problem of having both sold and unsold data in table link since you already have a column specific for storing status which can easily query for wanted data.

Comment: Hi, Please, provide input data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are misunderstanding the basics here. Creating a table is one thing and interacting(**C**reating, **R**eading, **U**pdating and **D**eleting data) with it is a different thing.

Lets assume that you have your products table's structure like this for example.

```sql
CREATE TABLE products ( 
    item_no INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    item VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
    qty SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL , 
    price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL , 
    status ENUM('SOLD','UNSOLD') NOT NULL
);
```

To link this to your what-ever table (in this case `links`), You just do.

```sql
CREATE TABLE links(
    s_no             INT PRIMARY KEY,
    product_item_no  INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ( product_item_no ) 
        REFERENCES products ( item_no ) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE 
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

notice there is no need for the status because it can be fetched from the products table by joining the two tables.

for example by issuing a select query at a later point in time.

eg.

```sql
SELECT l.*, p.status FROM links l
    LEFT JOIN products p ON p.item_no = l.product_item_no
WHERE p.status = 'SOLD';
```